# How often slave gets updated in master slave configuration?

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication, master-slave

We have set up master-slave configuration and I need to know at what time slave is getting updated OR how often slave is getting updated. Where can I see the settings saved for replication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manual contains the needed info under this FAQ point:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-replication.html#qandaitem-B-13-1-3

see last line of below output

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                Master_Host: localhost
                Master_User: root
                Master_Port: 3306
              Connect_Retry: 3
            Master_Log_File: gbichot-bin.005
        Read_Master_Log_Pos: 79
             Relay_Log_File: gbichot-relay-bin.005
              Relay_Log_Pos: 548
      Relay_Master_Log_File: gbichot-bin.005
           Slave_IO_Running: Yes
          Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
            Replicate_Do_DB:
        Replicate_Ignore_DB:
         Replicate_Do_Table:
     Replicate_Ignore_Table:
    Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                 Last_Errno: 0
                 Last_Error:
               Skip_Counter: 0
        Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 79
            Relay_Log_Space: 552
            Until_Condition: None
             Until_Log_File:
              Until_Log_Pos: 0
         Master_SSL_Allowed: No
         Master_SSL_CA_File:
         Master_SSL_CA_Path:
            Master_SSL_Cert:
          Master_SSL_Cipher:
             Master_SSL_Key:
      Seconds_Behind_Master: 8
```

Comment: the line `Seconds_Behind_Master` is 0 as seen in my system. what exactly I need is, how often slave checks if there are any updates.

Comment: never. update is triggered, slave does not check.

read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-formats.html